# Swift didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

I need to add a value to the selected row than in prepareForSegue that it does its action.But my prepareForSegue is doing the action before it.When i try to place the "performSegueWithIdentifier" it crashes,also i have added the id to the segue idenfifier in the storyboard.Im working with sqlite.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   selectedRow = indexPath.row
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "editSegue")
    {
        let viewController : WorkoutView = segue.destinationViewController as! WorkoutView
        viewController.workoutInfoData = marrStudentData.objectAtIndex(selectedRow) as! WorkoutInfo
        navigationItem.title = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get ?

Comment: When i remove the identifier in the story board add the performSegueWithIdentifier i get

Comment: 2015-10-24 17:53:41.331 MMA Spartan System Free[660:219419] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MMA_Spartan_System_Free.WorkoutsMenuView: 0x145567980>) has no segue with identifier 'editSegue''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1828d8f48 0x19748bf80 0x1881dcbc4 0x1000d6778 0x1000d6808 0x187fa231c 0x18805ff8c 0x18811c56c 0x1881294bc 0x187e5d984 0x18288fbd0 0x18288d974 0x18288dda4 0x1827bcca0 0x18d9f8088 0x187ed4ffc 0x1000b7228 0x197cda8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: has no segue with identifier 'editSegue''  .... so You should give a like  'editSegue'  to the segue to solve this error !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the selected indexPaths from tableView in your prepare for segue

```
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "editSegue")
        {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                let viewController : WorkoutView = segue.destinationViewController as! WorkoutView
                viewController.workoutInfoData = marrStudentData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! WorkoutInfo
                navigationItem.title = ""
            }
        }
    }
```